# Android Web view Load https website to get user location : failed

Tags: android-studio, geolocation, android-webview

i have a problem when loading website url in webview in android app, the following error displayed "user denied the request for geolocation" .

kindly note that the website is hosted on internet server and using https and the website works well on all browsers(chrome, firefox, edge, etc..) and return successfully user's location longtitude and latitdue.

those options are also enabled in the android application(setJavaScriptEnabled, setGeolocationEnabled) and added internet permission, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to the manifest file.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: i also tried to load "https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation" to android webview and didnt work too.

Comment: I just tried `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` with local js file and no problem to get the lat/long. Some questions:

1. Did you get same error message if it's using file:/// ? 2. You android version. 3. Attach your index.html minimal code which reproduce that error. 4. Attach your webview code minimal code which reproduced that error. 5. Try to find the line `WebViewFactory` from logcat to see which webview package is using.

I'm not Android guru but someone else might able to answer if you give those information.